# Anonymous methods vs Extension method vs Lambda expression vs Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Every time I go through an interview, I find these hard to define.
Could some body please explain here what is the difference between these and how they are related? The interviewer is never satisfied with my answer. What exactly he wants to listen I never understand?

**Anonymous methods:**

> I say these are the simple inline functions.

**Extension methods:**

> These are the methods that we can add on fly without implementing any
>   interface.

**Lambda expression:**

> I say it is a used to query an object and i start telling them
>   syntax's.

**Linq:**

> I say it is a query language that query to any collection. And i start
>   telling the syntax.

I am using these things for past six months, but unable to define properly.

Comment: How about you explain it to us like you are doing an interview and we can help you clear up your misconceptions.

Comment: ok i edit it above how i define it..

Comment: Have you thought about asking google?  This seems like a pretty reputable answer:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/01/10/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-one.aspx

Comment: I seen that article but that i find tough to understand.

Comment: @sous2817 pretty reputable, high praise! :)

Comment: Read the language specification if there are features you don't understand, and then come back here and ask a more specific question. This question is too vague.

Comment: @EricLippert I was looking for the "convey inflection" tag that would clearly show that I was playing down the importance of the author :)

Comment: @EricLippert : I am sorry..

Comment: No worries. Your definitions that you just added are reasonable except for lambda expressions. Read up on those. They are basically a better syntax for anonymous methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous methods and lambdas are very similar, with lambdas being a more powerful subtype of AMs. LINQ uses lambdas to enable most of its functionality.

In C# v2, creating delegates could be done by passing a code block as a parameter to the delegate constructor, like in this example from MSDN:

```
button1.Click += delegate(System.Object o, System.EventArgs e)
               { System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Click!"); }
```

Lambdas are inline, anonymous methods that are a direct subclass of the appropriate parameterization of `Func` or `Action`. If a method `Foo` takes a parameter of type `Func<int, string>`, then you could call it like this:

```
Foo(x => "the number " + (string)x);
```

And the lambda `x => "the number " + (string)x` would be the `Func`, taking an integer and producing a string when `Invoke` is called on it.

LINQ is a great way to handle data. Many of its methods, like `Max`, can take a custom function to determine sorting or control whatever the LINQ operation does. Pass a lambda (or, if you want, a reference to a named function) and it will be used by LINQ to perform the operation. Example:

```
// list is a List<string>
Console.WriteLine(list.Max(str => str.Length));
```

The maximum (longest) string will be printed.

**EDIT** after you edited: Extension methods are syntactic sugar that the compiler helps implement. They're methods that are defined in a different place than a class/interface/struct, but can be written as if they were a member of that thing. LINQ's methods are made more easily accessible as extension methods on `IEnumerable<T>`.